# Watermark in video with ffmpeg Center-Top

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i currently have 2 commands where i can select to put my watermark top-left or top-right of the video but i also have a watermark,which i wish to put in center-top,but i could only put it in center of the video,can someone pease help me with putting the waternmark on center top of the video ? here's what im using

```
$watermark = '-vf "movie='.$text_logo_path.' [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:main_h/2-overlay_h/2 [out]"
```

how can i get it to be in Top-Center ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: center overlay image]

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex "overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2" out
```

Use `-filter_complex` when you have multiple inputs and or outputs; this option also allows you to omit the [`movie`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) source filter. See the [`overlay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) video filter documentation for more info.

Comment: Was actually waiting for your replay,saw you solved alot of FFMPEG problems and couldn't find anyway to contact you directly,so posted this thread and anyways it worked :D thanks!!